# How to get payment per iOS app report?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Let say I'm a company and I have 2 subcontractors developing 2 different iOs apps. I want to know how much each app is earning to pay them accordingly.

How can I know how much each iOs app is earning per month ?

From the iTunes Connect's "Payments and Financial reports" page I can get the payment per country per month but I didn't find the payment per app that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get how much each iOs app is earning per month using my own project and the CSV report files from Apple.

Java version : https://github.com/est-seb/revenuePerAppJava

Javascript (Node + electron) version : https://github.com/est-seb/RevenuePerApp

Answer (score 1):

You are able to get app sales by **SKU** and a lot more, but you must generate a report first.

In payments and financial records module there is a button in the top right named **Create Reports**. Click this button and select the regions you want to include. It defaults to all regions. Once the report is generated you can download it and view the data it contains. Each region is archived and once unarchived it is in **CSV** format. You can view it in a text editor which is rather ugly, or a spreadsheet or enter it into your own database with a custom dashboard for whatever serves your purpose.

For additional info go to the **Resources and Help** module in **iTunes connect**. In the news feed there is an entry **Feb 25 2016** titled **Introducing the new Payments and Financial Records**. This has additional info that may be useful.

Comment: OK, so I need to make a program that will process all the CSV files and make the addition of all payments per app for each country to get the total per app, right ?

Comment: There are (free) services that do that for you:
**AppFigures** (we've been using them for 4+ years): https://appfigures.com/  
**AppAnnie** (not so much a fan personally): https://www.appannie.com/  
**LaunchKit** (goes directly to Slack, but not real "overview"): https://launchkit.io/sales/

Comment: I tried AppFigures and AppAnnie and both total payments for a month are different than the one given by iTunesConnect (around 5% difference)... Not sure why, I suppose it could be related to the fact that my iTunesConnect account's currency is euro so a conversion could give a slightly different result... Anyway I would like to have a 100% accurate payments total.

Comment: With different currencies you'll always get minor differences caused by exchange rates. As far as I know you can get also the monthly payment reports into AppFigures. If you read Apple's docs the only reports that matter are the monthly payments (because they are final). Even working iTunes Connect you'll get different numbers if you compare App Analytics, Sales & Trends and the monthly Financial Reports.

Comment: I added up the iTunesConnect financial reports through my own code and I could retrieve the correct monthly payments (3 to 5 euro cents difference for some month but that's ok).